# ¿Cómo mandar datos de tabla que llené con javascript a PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hice una tabla con HTML y la fui llenando con botones. Estos botones tienen funciones que iban llenando el tbody, pero ahora no sé cómo puedo recibirlos en una página de PHP y poder insertarlos a una base de datos.

```html
<form id="formulario" method="POST"  action="get_pedido.php"> 
    <table id="tablita">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>COLOR</th>
          <th>METROS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>      
    <tbody>

    </tbody></table>
      
      <input type="submit" id="insertarpedido" value="Aceptar" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

Tengo un botón antes que manda a ese formulario y ejecuta la función javascript que tengo, y llena la tabla.

```javascript
function insertarPed(){
      $('#tablita tr:not(:first)').remove();
      let inputValue = document.getElementById("color-1").value;
      let cant = document.getElementById("cantidad").value; 
      let fila = "<tr><td>" +inputValue+ "</td> <td>" + cant+ "</td> </tr>";
      let btn = document.createElement("TR");
      btn.innerHTML=fila;
      document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de la tabla que quiero pasar a php, pero que las filas ingresadas se inserten por cada fila a la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dejame entender esto... creaste informacion estatica manualmente, la pusiste en una tabla y quieres metrallar la base de datos con la informacion de la tabla que creaste?

Comment: jeje sii, solo son 20 datos opcionales que tenia que agregar por eso el color-1,cantidad.. y asi va hasta 20, entonces el usuario toma un color-n y una cantidad-n de ese color, si va tomando cada de esas 20 opciones se van agregando a la tabla, y ya esta, ahora quiero meterlo a BD pero no se como mandarlos

Comment: Puedes mandarlo de distintas formas, una de ellas es hacer en vez de una tabla un formulario, o pasar las variables con fetch desde el cliente al servidor

Comment: @sys-5aid-Cook Puedes mostrar el HTML de la tabla  con filas?

Comment: y que has intentado para enviarlo??? no veo ningun intento  esperas que hagamos el codigo por ti???

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @DavidGonzalo si es lo que vi que con fetch o api fetch pero no se como recorrer cada td de mi tbody y mandar los datos encontrados.

Comment: @WilfredoAleman sii pues la tabla HTML es tal como lo puse, fui agregando al TBODY con javascript y se muestra asi como la imagen que acabo de subir

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Intente mandarlo como un form normal, y a cada TR de la tabla que inserte con javascript le puse un input y su respectivo name para poder cacharlos con POST en PHP pero no funciono, luego intente utilizar AJAX, con una API Fetch, se como es la estructura pero no se como mandar mis datos y cacharlos en el PHP, espero que me puedan orientar como hacerlo

Comment: solo puedes enviar por POST y GET campos el texto plano que agregas en tu tabla no se va a enviar ... tendrias que adicionalmente agregar un campo type hidden ... colocandoles un name diferente y en el valor lo que quieres enviar...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 entonces si servira asi aunque los mande desde javascript??

Comment: enviandolo por el metodo normal; para hacerlo con javascript debes leer los campos crear un form data y enviarlo con ajax...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ok, lo hare del metodo normal agregando el hidden, y sino investigare sobre mandarlo con Ajax nuevamente, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto te ayude, es un ejemplo muy simple, cualquier duda comentas:

```
    <!--generamos una tabla de 3x2 con fechas -->

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="1_1" class="celda 1_1" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="1_2" class="celda 1_2" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="1_3" class="celda 1_3" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="2_1" class="celda 2_1" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="2_2" class="celda 2_2" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="2_3" class="celda 2_3" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="3_1" class="celda 3_1" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="3_2" class="celda 3_2" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" id="3_3" class="celda 3_3" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonenviar">Enviar</button>
<script>
//buscamos todos los objetos con la class que contenga la palabra  celda
let celdas = document.getElementsByClassName('celda');
let botonenviar = document.getElementsByClassName('botonenviar');
botonenviar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //enviamos los campos con la class celda por fetch
    for (let i = 0; i < celdas.length; i++) {
        let id = celdas[i].id;
        let valor = celdas[i].value;
        fetch('/envios.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: id,
                valor: valor
            })
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

es decir te diría que pusieras una id única por celda y una clase común para todas, buscas las celdas con la misma class y mandas una array al servidor(entiendo que es php), después desde el servidor ya haces la magia .

Comment: Oh si! así es como quería verlo, no daba con exactitud mi lógica y no sabia muy como utilizar la API fetch, esto es muy entendible de como lo vi en muchos lados, si me sirvió! muchas gracias bro